# Ocelot Gateway Latency Issue

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, ocelot

I deployed Ocelot Gateway and Services using .NET core app both on IIS. But there is an issue in which if I access the endpoint using gateway, I get a 2secs or more before it returns the response but when I directly access the endpoint using the service it only took milliseconds to return the response. For IIS setup I already tried this [Article](https://www.leansentry.com/guide/reset-restart-recycle-iis/max-application-pool-warmup#install-the-application-initialization-module)

I'm expecting it should be the same when I Api response latency when I use both gateway and services.

Comment: Is it always 2 seconds for every request, or just the first request?

Comment: Have you run a trace?

Comment: Every request I made even the first request. I already resolve the warm query issue on my services the problem is when I use the gateway to call those services. They are on the same server using localhost connection so I'm not sure why it return those.

Comment: This could be due to Ocelot trying to connect over IPv6 but your service only being available over IPv4. You could check, e.g., using Wireshark. If this is the case, make sure to use IPv4 in your ocelot route configuration. This also means using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.